# How to install scipy in Python3.5 virtual env | windows 10?

Tags: python, tensorflow, scipy, jupyter-notebook

I have Anaconda (Python 3.6) in my Windows 10. This includes Scipy. I am also using a virtual Python 3.5 env to support TensorFlow. Now, the problem is that I cannot import Scipy while I'm inside this virtual env.

I have tried:
    pip install scipy (didn't work)
    easy-install scipy (didn't work)
I also visited http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy to look for suitable package to install but I could not figure out which numpy+mkl and scipy combination to download.

I'll be grateful for help. I know that there already exist similar questions on this issue. But I could not find answer to my problem anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you're inside your virtual environment for TensorFlow, try

```
conda install -c anaconda scipy=0.19.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to create VirtualEnv with Python 3.5 as currently there is NO TensorFlow release for Python 3.6.

steps:

create Python 3.5 VirtualEnv:

```
conda create -n py35 python=3.5 anaconda
```

activate it

```
activate py35
```

install TensorFlow

```
conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge tensorflow
```