# How to install tensorflow in windows 10 using python 3.5.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow

On giving this command

```
C:\Users\Sudhit>python -c "from pip import pep425tags;print(pep425tags.supported_tags)"
[('cp27', 'cp27m', 'win_amd64'), ('cp27', 'none', 'win_amd64'), ('py2', 'none', 'win_amd64'), ('cp27', 'none', 'any'), ('cp2', 'none', 'any'), ('py27', 'none', 'any'), ('py2', 'none', 'any'), ('py26', 'none', 'any'), ('py25', 'none', 'any'), ('py24', 'none', 'any'), ('py23', 'none', 'any'), ('py22', 'none', 'any'), ('py21', 'none', 'any'), ('py20', 'none', 'any')]
```

I am not getting python 3, as I have installed python 3.5.2 then why I am getting this result?

Comment: you may want to check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43912875/5741205)

Answer (score 0):

Use anaconda . Installation is much simpler.

Comment: I facing the same issue also with anaconda